# Creating JLabel and JTextField at runtime

Tags: java, swing, runtime, jlabel, jtextfield

In my application, a db query is executed. The query gets the column names of the table. I want to make a jlabel and jtextfield based on the column names of my database. And get their values if i press the submit button. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

I've tried the following codes.. but no luck..

```
public void getColumn(){
        String sql = "SELECT * from user";

        try {
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            int count = 1; 

            ArrayList<String> columns= new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i = 1; i<= columnCount; i++){
                columns.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
               / System.out.println(String.valueOf(columns));
            }
            ArrayList<JTextField> fields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
        for(int i = 0; i <columns.size();i++){
                JLabel jl = new JLabel(String.valueOf(columns.get(i)));
            jp.add(jl);
            JTextField f = new JTextField(String.valueOf(columns.get(i)));
            fields.add(f);
            jp.add(f);
                        this.revalidate();
                        this.repaint();
               }
```

---

I don't need to output my query in a JTable. I just need my column names in my database then create a jlabel and jtextfield at runtime based on that.

As an example.

This is my user table..

```
id | fName | mName | lName
```

if i click a button...
the outcome would be this..

```
id | ___________________ 
Name | _______________ 
mName | _______________ 
lName | _______________
```

lines refering to textboxes...

Comment: Did you try to code something by yourself ? what is your concrete problem ?

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

- use [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) instead of arrays of [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)s/[JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)s
- all changes to [JTables view should be done in XxxTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)
- output from [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) could be hard and long event, then you'll probably issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), Swing Gui could be freeze or could be unresponsible for Mouse/Key events untill JDBC ended
- Swing is single threaded and all output to the Swing GUI must be done on [Event Dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), Swing is asynchronous from this view, and all updates are done in one moment

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved my problem guys.

This problem has been bugging me for the past two days. Finally, after a lot of trial and error, I realized it was an issue concerning selecting the correct LayoutManager.

By default, containers (i.e. JPanel, JScrollPanel) added with drag and drop inside the NetBeans uses the GroupLayout. Hence, if you try to add a new runtime generated components to those containers, they won’t show up.

To solve this problem is to reset the Layout manager. So far, GridLayout and FlowLayout managers works great.

```
 jpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
```

And, this solved my problem.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, please don't ask new questions using the answer form. It should be posted as a new question (with more detail than provided above).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'm just a newbie here.